# What should I do when this error occurs? Alt-Ergo: "Unknown error"

Tags: frama-c, alt-ergo

When I run the WP example, there is an error, and i don't know what it is.

```
/*@ requires \valid(a) && \valid(b);
  @ ensures A: *a == \old(*b) ;
  @ ensures B: *b == \old(*a) ;
  @ assigns *a,*b ;
@*/
void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
    // int tmp = *b;
    // *b = *a;
    // *a = tmp;
}
```

### this is the error in console of frama-c-gui

```
[wp] No updated script.
[wp] [Alt-Ergo 2.3.1] Goal typed_swap_ensures_A : Failed
  Unknown error
```

---

### the output after executing " frama-c -wp -wp-rte swap.c"

```
[kernel] Parsing swap.c (with preprocessing)
[rte] annotating function swap
[wp] 8 goals scheduled
[wp] [Alt-Ergo 2.0.0] Goal typed_swap_assert_rte_mem_access : Failed
  Unknown error
[wp] [Alt-Ergo 2.0.0] Goal typed_swap_ensures_A : Failed
  Unknown error
[wp] [Alt-Ergo 2.0.0] Goal typed_swap_assert_rte_mem_access_3 : Failed
  Unknown error
[wp] Proved goals:    5 / 8
  Qed:               5  (16ms)
  Alt-Ergo 2.0.0:    0  (failed: 3)
```

---

Thank you very much if you can help me

Comment: I'm getting these exact errors for the exact same file. Did you ever figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

Which frama-c version do you have ?

With `Alt-Ergo 2.3.3` and `frama-c 21.1` (Scandium)

```
[bash] frama-c -wp -wp-rte ex.c
[kernel] Parsing ex.c (with preprocessing)
[rte] annotating function swap
[wp] 8 goals scheduled
[wp] Proved goals:    8 / 8
  Qed:               5  (1ms-3ms-6ms)
  Alt-Ergo 2.3.3:    3  (8ms-12ms) (50)
```

With `Alt-Ergo 2.0.0` and `frama-c 21.1`, I get an error but it's different from yours:

```
frama-c -wp -wp-rte ex.c
[kernel] Parsing ex.c (with preprocessing)
[rte] annotating function swap
[wp] 8 goals scheduled
[wp] [Alt-Ergo 2.3.3] Goal typed_swap_assert_rte_mem_access : Failed
  Failure : File generation error :  syntax error
[wp] [Alt-Ergo 2.3.3] Goal typed_swap_ensures_A : Failed
  Failure : File generation error :  syntax error
[wp] [Alt-Ergo 2.3.3] Goal typed_swap_assert_rte_mem_access_3 : Failed
  Failure : File generation error :  syntax error
[wp] Proved goals:    5 / 8
  Qed:               5  (1ms-2ms-5ms)
  Alt-Ergo 2.3.3:    0  (failed: 3)
```

Comment: Did you refresh the Why3 configuration between the two trials? (Frama-C 21: `rm ~/.why3.conf ; why3 config --full-config`, Frama-C 22: `rm ~/.why3.conf ; why3 config --detect`).

Comment: When I use the command:**why3 config --detect**,the result is **Prover Alt-Ergo version 2.3.3 is not known to be supported.
Known versions for this prover: 2.3.1, 2.3.0.
Known old versions for this prover: .
1 prover(s) added (including 1 prover(s) with an unrecognized version)
Save config to /home/charles/.why3.conf**. So my version of Alt-Ergo is 2.3.0

Comment: And what version of Frama-C do you use?

Comment: The version of Frama-C is 21.1

Comment: With Frama-C 21.1 you should do: `rm ~/.why3.conf ; why3 config --full-config` .

(And for Frama-C 22+, `rm ~/.why3.conf ; why3 config --detect`).

Note that the fact that a prover is not supported by Why3 does not necessarily means that it won't work, just that it has not been tested so far.

Comment: I had downgraded the version of Alt-Ergo to 2.3.1，and do: `rm ~/.why3.conf ; why3 config --full-config`.But it didn't work.The output is `[wp] [Alt-Ergo 2.3.1] Goal typed_swap_ensures_A : Failed
[wp] [Cache] found:1`

Comment: do: `frama-c -wp swap.c`. The output is:`[kernel] Parsing swap.c (with preprocessing)
[wp] Warning: Missing RTE guards
[wp] 2 goals scheduled
[wp] [Alt-Ergo 2.3.1] Goal typed_swap_ensures_A : Failed
[wp] [Cache] found:1
[wp] Proved goals:    1 / 2
  Qed:               1
  Alt-Ergo 2.3.1:    0  (cached: 1) (failed: 1)`

Comment: Try removing the existing cache entries `rm .frama-c` in the directory where you run the proof. It seems that WP does a cache hit on the failed PO.